# Using local storage, display the amount of time in days between user visits to this page by the user's agent

Tags: local-storage

Unfortunately, when the users visit the site for the first time, they will see the number of days elapsed between 1 Jan 1970 and today's date. Same situation for the number of elapsed seconds. It is only after refreshing the page that the correct values will be displayed.

The expected result should be a message for the user saying "This is your first visit on our website.  Welcome!" and "n/a" for the number of seconds. I have tried to set variables to 0 before I computed the final values but I did not get the expected values.

```
//* Calculate Number of days between visits *//
// milliseconds to days constant = 1000 ms/s * 60 s/m * 60 m/h * 24 h/day
const msToDays = 84600000;

// initialize display elements
const daysElapsedDisplay = document.querySelector(".days-elapsed");
const secondsElapsedDisplay = document.querySelector(".seconds-elapsed");

// ms today since 1 Jan 1970
const msToday = Date.now();

// Get the stored VALUE for the msLastVisit-ls KEY in localStorage if it exists. If the msLastVisit KEY is missing, then assign 0 to the msLastVisit variable.
let msLastVisit = Number(window.localStorage.getItem("msLastVisit-ls")) || 0;

// Time elapsed in ms between last visit and today
let msElapsed = msToday - msLastVisit;

msLastVisit = msToday;

// Compute number of days since last visit
const daysElapsed = Math.round(msElapsed / msToDays);
// Compute number of seconds since last visit
const secElapsed = Math.round(msElapsed / 1000);

// Determine if this is the first visit or display the number of days since the user last visited the site.
if (msLastVisit !== 0) {
  daysElapsedDisplay.textContent = daysElapsed;
  secondsElapsedDisplay.textContent = secElapsed;
} else {
  daysElapsedDisplay.textContent = `This is your first visit on our website.  Welcome!`;
  secondsElapsedDisplay.textContent = "n/a";
}

// Store the new msLastVisit into localStorage, key=msLastVisit-ls
localStorage.setItem("msLastVisit-ls", msLastVisit);
```

Comment: Maybe: `let msLastVisit = Number(window.localStorage.getItem("msLastVisit-ls")) || msToday;`, then the condition below: `if (msElapsed  !== 0) { ... }`?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It works!
You can check my college project assignment at https://giuseppebrandi-byui.github.io/wdd230/chamber/index.html 
The number of days and seconds is by the footer.
Regards
Giuseppe